# Why have I UnauthorizedAccessException when I use Service Bus MessagingFactory?

Tags: servicebus

I have configured authorization via certificate. When I use NamespaceManager to GetSubscription works fine, but when I try execute any method from MessagingFactory I receive System.UnauthorizedAccessException.

```
string connectionString = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString");

var namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
SubscriptionDescription subscriptionDescription = namespaceManager.GetSubscription("testTopic", "testSubscription"); // executed properly

var messagingFactory = MessagingFactory.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
var exist = namespaceManager.TopicExists("TestTopic"); // throws exception
```

Stack trace:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147024891
  Message=The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. Authorization failed for specified action: Manage..TrackingId:d8648c5a-5185-41c8-b787-72332403b7d9_*******,TimeStamp:2014-07-14 08:34:22
  Source=Microsoft.ServiceBus
```

What's the matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For use NamespaceManager you must be in ManageUsers in Service Bus Namespace. To add user to existing namespace you can use ps [Set-SBNamespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj248750(v=azure.10).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You must be in the ManageUsers list in Service Bus Namespace *or* have the Authorization rule that gives you the Manage right on the Topic that you are getting the subscriptions for.